# Adding and subtracting multiple columns into new column

Tags: text-processing, awk, csv-simple

I have copied a partial csv file.

```
publish_date,headline_text,likes_count,comments_count,shares_count,love_count,wow_count,haha_count,sad_count,thankful_count,angry_count
20030219,aba decides against community broadcasting licence,1106,118,109,155,6,5,2,0,6
20030219,act fire witnesses must be aware of defamation,137,362,67,0,0,0,0,0,0
20030219,a g calls for infrastructure protection summit,357,119,212,0,0,0,0,0,0
20030219,air nz staff in aust strike for pay rise,826,254,105,105,21,45,7,0,90
20030219,air nz strike to affect australian travellers,693,123,153,17,113,4,103,0,7
20030219,ambitious olsson wins triple jump,488,57,161,0,0,0,0,0,0
20030219,antic delighted with record breaking barca,386,60,80,3,4,0,93,0,68
20030219,aussie qualifier stosur wastes four memphis match,751,45,297,0,0,0,0,0,0
20030219,aust addresses un security council over iraq,3847,622,141,1,0,0,0,0,0
20030219,australia is locked into war timetable opp,1330,205,874,0,0,0,0,0,0
20030219,australia to contribute 10 million in aid to iraq,3530,130,0,23,16,4,1,0,0
20030219,barca take record as robson celebrates birthday in,13875,331,484,0,0,0,0,0,0
20030219,bathhouse plans move ahead,11202,450,2576,433,51,20,4,0,34
20030219,big hopes for launceston cycling championship,3988,445,955,0,0,0,0,0,0
20030219,big plan to boost paroo water supplies,460,101,92,0,0,0,0,0,0
20030219,blizzard buries united states in bills,303,223,193,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

I would like to find a shell command that will help me able to make a new column that will add up each entries (likes_count+ love_count + thankful_count) - (angry_count + sad_count) and name the column emotional_polarity.

I have tried

```
awk -F , {$12=$3+$6+$10-$11-$9;}{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10,$11,$12} file
```

but it does not work for some reason the columns become mixed together.
i think this may be because I am losing the comma when I perform this

Comment: Beware of commas in the headlines.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

set OFS ([**O**utput **F**ield **S**eparator](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Output-Separators)) too so that you don't lose commas. It loses the commas when you do `$12=$3+$6+$10-$11-$9`, i.e, setting/updating any column's value which in this case *awk* does the field splitting on the current line based on the OFS internal variable, which is Space character by default, so setting it to a comma will keep those on output when printing.

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FS=OFS="," }
          { $(NF+1)=(NR==1? "emotional_polarity" : $3+$6+$10-$11-$9); print }' infile
```

or simply append the new updates to the current input line:

```
awk -F, '{ $0=$0 FS (NR==1? "emotional_polarity" : $3+$6+$10-$11-$9); print }' infile
```

from the [awk manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html):

> **FS**
> The input field separator (see section [Specifying How Fields Are
> Separated](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Field-Separators)). The value is a single-character string or a multicharacter
> regular expression that matches the separations between fields in an
> input record.
>
> **OFS**
> The output field separator (see section [Output Separators](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Output-Separators)). It is
> output between the fields printed by a print statement. Its default
> value is " ", a string consisting of a single space.

Answer (score 3):

If it'd be useful to refer to the fields by their names (e.g. if the order of the columns can change):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
NR == 1 {
    $(NF+1) = "emotional_polarity"
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        f[$i] = i
    }
}
NR > 1 {
    $(f["emotional_polarity"]) = \
        ( $(f["likes_count"]) + $(f["love_count"]) + $(f["thankful_count"]) ) \
            - ( $(f["angry_count"]) + $(f["sad_count"]) )

}
{ print }
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
publish_date,headline_text,likes_count,comments_count,shares_count,love_count,wow_count,haha_count,sad_count,thankful_count,angry_count,emotional_polarity
20030219,aba decides against community broadcasting licence,1106,118,109,155,6,5,2,0,6,1253
20030219,act fire witnesses must be aware of defamation,137,362,67,0,0,0,0,0,0,137
20030219,a g calls for infrastructure protection summit,357,119,212,0,0,0,0,0,0,357
20030219,air nz staff in aust strike for pay rise,826,254,105,105,21,45,7,0,90,834
20030219,air nz strike to affect australian travellers,693,123,153,17,113,4,103,0,7,600
20030219,ambitious olsson wins triple jump,488,57,161,0,0,0,0,0,0,488
20030219,antic delighted with record breaking barca,386,60,80,3,4,0,93,0,68,228
20030219,aussie qualifier stosur wastes four memphis match,751,45,297,0,0,0,0,0,0,751
20030219,aust addresses un security council over iraq,3847,622,141,1,0,0,0,0,0,3848
20030219,australia is locked into war timetable opp,1330,205,874,0,0,0,0,0,0,1330
20030219,australia to contribute 10 million in aid to iraq,3530,130,0,23,16,4,1,0,0,3552
20030219,barca take record as robson celebrates birthday in,13875,331,484,0,0,0,0,0,0,13875
20030219,bathhouse plans move ahead,11202,450,2576,433,51,20,4,0,34,11597
20030219,big hopes for launceston cycling championship,3988,445,955,0,0,0,0,0,0,3988
20030219,big plan to boost paroo water supplies,460,101,92,0,0,0,0,0,0,460
20030219,blizzard buries united states in bills,303,223,193,0,0,0,0,0,0,303
```

Answer (score 1):

I would make two changes in what you have tried. This is your command:

`awk -F , '{$12=$3+$6+$10-$11-$9;}{print }' file`

When `OFS=","` is used in `BEGIN` block, half of our work is done. This is how fields are separated when printed. Next `if(NR==1) $NF="emotional_polarity"` does the other half. Though use of `$(NF+1)` is better than `$12`, I would use here `$12`. `$12=$a+..$b` add another field to $0. This increments NF value by one.  Therefore `if` statement changes last filed of line 1(`NR ==1`) to "emotional_polarity". I, now, place these two expressions in your command.

`awk -F , 'BEGIN{OFS=","}{$12=$3+$6+$10-$11-$9; if(NR==1) $NF="emotional_polarity"}{print }' file`

I tried it with an array like this:

```
awk -F',' 'BEGIN{OFS=","}
{arr[NR][1]=$0; arr[NR][2]=$3+$6+$10-$11-$9;}
END {
arr[1][2]="emotional_polarity";
for(i=1;i<=NR;i++) print arr[i][1], arr[i][2] }' file
```

`arr[NR][1]` takes all $0 output whereas `arr[NR][2]` takes calculation.

In `END` block, we set `arr[1][2]` to "emotional_polarity" because we wanted to name the field emotional_polarity. Then we tell `awk` to print.